# CSS adjustment for text size and font color

Tags: css

[image]

I am attempting to build a page that offers RSS feeds, just title and dates of articles. This is a snapshot of what I have so far.

```css
.wp-block-rss__item {font-size: 12px; color: #000000}
    
.wp-block-rss__item-publish-date {font-size: 12px; color: #000000}
```

Now, the second line of code, tells me I got something right. The font size and color both change the date to what I want. But the first line, only the font-size is working, I can change the article title (rss item) font size, but the color remains.

I am also trying to hide the bullet point image that flows from the RSS feed.

I tried

```css
.wp-block-rss_item::marker {display: none;}
```

For what it's worth, this is my first attempt at this type of CSS manipulation, I'm using the Chrome developer tools / inspector to help identify what needs changing. Prior, I had a web page that used a paid theme, and would just post "how do I do this?" and someone would reply with code within a day or two. I'd like to learn to do these simple things myself. Happy to clarify anything or post other details from the Chrome tool.

Adding this in response to comments - my inspector view looks like this. (yes, a different rss feed from posted above, same issue for all the feeds)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried declaring !important after the color value?

Comment: Have you tried `list-style:none;` on the list item elements or on the list element itself?

Comment: You probably have another CSS rule that overrides your `color` in the `.wp-block-rss__item`. With Crome developer tools, once you select that element you should see all the CSS that gets applied to it, check out that and you'll see where it gets overridden and you'll be one step closer to fix the issue.

Yes, you could use `!important` as others said but imho it's not a good practice to get into, it's better to use a more specific CSS selector, will cause way less issues in the future

Comment: important did not work. I added the view from inspector, since I'm not really understanding the next step.

Comment: Can you add the HTML and CSS snippet it makes it easier for us to help you. Also as goes for the color not working, did you try to be more specific in your CSS. Just try to add an `id` and give it a color to see if it's changing then your problem is a CSS Specifcifty issue.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica on the inspector, when you click on an element you should see another pane opening (it should be on the right or on the bottom, usually) there you'll see all the CSS that's applied to the element, with that it will be easier to help you. Just by looking at the screenshot you should try something like this `.wp-block-rss__item a {color: #000000}` and see if it works like this

Comment: @Daniel - That worked. I went back, and just added the 'a' to what I wrote, and that did it. Glad it worked, and very appreciative. But can you tell me how you knew that was it? I am here to learn, and don't feel I have any more knowledge than when I woke up.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica Good to know it worked! Give me some time and i'll write an answer so it's easier for people to find it, if they have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writing this to make it easier for people to find the solution that i wrote in the comments.

To fix this the easiest way is to change the `.wp-block-rss__item {font-size: 12px; color: #000000}` rule into

```
.wp-block-rss__item a {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000
}
```

Why does this happen? To make it easy, you are dealing with CSS specificity, which is what makes CSS so flexible (while also making it difficult for people to approach it). So, to get on your point, every HTML element has it's "basic" styling, in the case of an `a` like yours it's blue colored and underlined like it was showing in the first screenshot, but why was your code changing the font-size but not the color? Simply because the "basic" styling of the `a` doesn't have a font-size, but it has a color and that color was overriding your rule, this is because for CSS the rules that were applied to the `a` are more specific than the rules applied to `.wp-block-rss__item` which was the parent of the parent of your `a`. Changing the rule like i suggested you tells the browser that every anchor inside a `.wp-block-rss__item` has to get that styling, which, in this case is more specific than the "basic" styling. I'll give you an example, maybe it's easier to understand

```css
.parent{
  color: red;
}

.parent .green{
  color: green;
}

.kid a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.kid .custom-link{
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span> This text is red </span> <br>
  <span class="green">This text is green</span> <br>
  <a href="#">This is a normal link</a> <br>
  <div class="kid">
    <a href="#">This is a custom styled link</a> <br> <br>
    <a href="#" class="custom-link">This is another custom styled link with a more specific selector</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the normal link doesn't get the color of the `.parent` (red) BUT when i use a more specific class `.kid a` both links in the `kid` element get the style without the underline and the color black. The second link has a more specific class so it gets the color from that.

You can read [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and [over here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) for more info. I know this might look scary and hard to understand, but trust me, work with CSS for a month or so and it will become natural.

Hope I explained myself good enough, let me know if you don't understand something

Answer (score 2):

Try using `!important` behind your statements to override already given properties.

For example:

```
.wp-block-rss__item {font-size: 12px; color: #000000 !important}
```

Comment: I thank you for the suggestion. Probably useful in the future, but in this case, it's not changing anything. again, thx for the response.